# ftp copy multiple files from unix

Tags: unix, ftp

I want to copy files with a same prefix from one ftp server to local directory
Here is what i did

```
ftp ftp.domain.com  << FTP_START

cd $dir
get $fileprefix*  localdir/ftpdata/

bye

    FTP_START
```

I get error `$fileprefix*: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple files use `mget` instead of `get`

Comment: oh thanks. it seems it did select the files required but I get an error  like this    " /home/user/1/ftpdata: The system cannot find the path specified.
fileprefix28.csv? mget fileprefix12.csv? mget fileprefix27.csv? mget fileprefix11.csv?   " .   But the given path actually exists. any idea?